# I'm unable to pass variable from a function to the main code in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently writing a code for a specific form of output message display and facing troubles which setting values for a variable when function is called. Also, an error message " op: command not found " is arising whenever the code is executed.

This is the expected output:

```
RIU 1 is online/offline
RIU 2 is online/offline
RIU 1 is online/offline
RIU 2 is online/offline
RIU 1 is online/offline
RIU 2 is online/offline
RIU 1 is online/offline
RIU 2 is online/offline
```

This is the output which I am getting:

```
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
line 10: op: command not found
RIU  is online/offline
```

My script looks as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Ping Test for RIU"
    read -p "Enter the number of RIU : " x
    echo -e "Initiating RIU Ping Test\n"
    a=101
    y=x*2
    for ((i=1; i<=y; i++))
    do
            op i
            if ping -c1 -W1 192.168.1."$a" 1>/dev/null
            then
                    echo "RIU "$b" is online"
            else
                    echo "RIU "$b" is offline"
            fi
            let "a+=1"
    done
    echo -e "\nRIU Ping Test Complete"


    op()
    {
    c = $i
    d = expr $c % 2
    if [ $d -eq 1]
    then
            b = 1
    else
            b = 2
    fi
    }
```

Comment: maybe you declare the function after it is used, try moving it before the code calling it.

Comment: Please copy/paste your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/, there are quite some mistakes.

Comment: Shell functions *must* be defined before they can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having passed your script over the spelling checker I mentioned, this looks promising (but I won't guarantee it works completely):

```
#!/bin/bash

    op()
    {
    c=$i
    d=$((c % 2))
    if [[ $d -eq 1 ]]
    then
            b=1
    else
            b=2
    fi
    }

    echo "Ping Test for RIU"
    read -p "Enter the number of RIU : " x
    echo -e "Initiating RIU Ping Test\n"
    a=101
    y=$((x*2))
    for ((i=1; i<=y; i++))
    do
            op "$i"
            if ping -c1 -W1 192.168.1."$a" 1>/dev/null
            then
                    echo "RIU "$b" is online"
            else
                    echo "RIU "$b" is offline"
            fi
            a=$((a+1))
    done
    echo -e "\nRIU Ping Test Complete"
```

Comment: Hi.

The fixes you suggested for my code work exactly the way i wanted. Thank you so much for your help